# Insert boolean column with maxmum value in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset like this :

[image]

I just want to add a column in sql which include the maximum of cycle for each unit as 1 and other cycles as 0 like this :

[image]

I try to write script as below but I have some error also I don't want to aggregate meauser1 and measure2 parameters :

select unit,
case when  max(cycle) then 1 end as "Failure"  from dbo.fd001
group by unit
order by unit

Comment: what type of DB are you using? pls add the related tag for the question.

Comment: also what is the error msg of your query?

Comment: That's SQL server, sorry.

Comment: and my error was: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'. Also, it was not such a good script because it would aggregate other two parameters (measure1 and measure2) but I dont want to group by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want window function :

```
select t.*, 
       (case when cycle = max(cycle) over (partition by unit) then 1 else end) as failure
from dbo.fd001 t;
```

Comment: Thank you ,  could you plase let me know what is difference between  partition by and group by ?

Comment: @SepideH. . . `GROUP BY` will aggregate the result (will minimize the rows) while `PARTITION` will only do aggregation on the base result & will not minimize the rows.